# OMNeT++: Error in import Module

Tags: omnet++

I am working on a project in OMNET++, I need to import  modules existing in the attached image[image].
 How I can import them to my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- make sure the MiXiM project is open
- right click in the project explorer on *your* project and select project references
- select the MiXiM project as a dependency
- Click OK